# Transform all columns records to lowercase

Tags: postgresql, functions

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 and I have a users table with a `login` column.

login names are case-sensitive, for example Bob, MikE, john.  I would like to transform all these records into lowercase.   How can I do that?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can do this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column=lower(column)
```

Refer to [www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: And if you'd like to know how many rows were affected, a simple `UPDATE table_name SET column = LOWER(column) WHERE column != LOWER(column);` will do.

Comment: I get this error `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` while trying this.